How to configure a outbound Proxy for nextcloud docker container
I've installed a nextcloud:30 docker container.
All outbound connections (i.e. to download plugins) must mandatory use a proxy in my Network.
Google & Co. returns only docs to config a reverse proxy, but this is not what I'm searching for.
I've tryed to set the enviroments below in uper- and lowercase letters but with no result.
      - HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.mydomain:8080/"
      - HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.mydomain:8080/"
      - NO_PROXY="localhost"

Any idears how I can set a outbound proxy?
